# Simple circle animation is only displayed the first time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to put circles on a map every second. This animation consists of 4 circles that are shown once a point is added on the map.

[image]

After the first time the animation is not repeated again. I do not know why this happens.  When new points are added, the animation does not happen again.

https://plnkr.co/edit/benkcHIINN9DCjvIvtEn?p=preview

```
    var aNumCircles=[1,2,4,5];
    function addpoints(){
        //add circle on map
        var coordenadas=map.latLngToLayerPoint([coordinates[cont].lat,coordinates[cont].long]);
            svg.append('circle').attr("cx",coordenadas.x)
            .attr("cy", coordenadas.y)
            .attr("r", 1)
            .style("fill",'red')
            .attr("class",'circulo_mapa')
        //add animation circles on map  
          var circle = svg.selectAll("circle").data(aNumCircles).enter().append('circle')
                  .attr("cx",coordenadas.x)
                  .attr("cy", coordenadas.y)
                  .attr("id", cont)
                  .attr("r", 0)

                  .style("stroke-width", function(d,i){ return 5 / (i+1) })
                  .attr("class", 'animation_explosion')
                  .transition()
                      .delay(function(d,i){ return Math.pow((i+1), 2.5) * 50 })
                      .duration(2000)
                      .ease('quad-in')
                  .attr("r", 25)
                  .style("stroke-opacity", 0)
                  .each("end", function (d,i) {
                      d3.select(this).remove();
                  });
        cont++;
    }
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        addpoints();
         if(cont==5){
            clearInterval(interval);
         }
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is just the first line in this selection:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(aNumCircles)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    //etc...
```

Since there are already circles in the SVG at the second time `addpoints()` runs, your "enter" selection will be empty.

Instead of that, it should be:

```
var circle = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(aNumCircles)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    //etc...
```

By using `selectAll(null)` you can be completely sure that your "enter" selection has all the elements in your data array.

Here is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/3u0er01thuj5P8e0XqO6?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. This is also solved with a 'for' cycle. Which of the two ways would be the most optimal ?. Maybe you can help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697728/put-a-circle-in-a-real-coordinate-using-d3-js I tried to use the zoom listener and recalculate each circle That is on the map, is the best way?

Comment: Definitely the enter selection. Try to avoid `for` loops for appending elements in a D3 code the best you can.